# Properties of periodic complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function and real on the lines $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \mathrm{Re}(z)=1\}, \{z\in\mathbb{C}: \mathrm{Re}(z)=2\}.$ Suppose $\text{lim}_{1\leq x \leq 2,y \to \infty}f(x,y)=0,$ where $z=x+iy.$

Could anyone advise me how to show $f(z)=0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \ ?$

I have established that $f$ is a periodic function.  Would it be helpful to the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please show how you established the periodicity?

Answer (score 0):

By the fact that $\lim_{1 \leq x \leq 2 , y \to \infty} f(x,y) = 0$ you deduce immediatly that $f$ is bounded in the strip $\{ 1 \leq \Re z \leq 2\}$. Since $f$ is periodic (is it periodic of period $1$?) you can deduce that $f$ is bounded in all of $\mathbb{C}$, hence it is a constant function by Liouville's theorem. And clearly this constant must be $0$.